# Thread Abort Exception in.NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, iis, asynchronous

From IIS, when I am calling some background task in a new thread, it only runs through if the task does not contain certain asynchronous calls.

If I call a background task in a new thread, that does contain these asynchronous calls, it does return a `ThreadAbortException`, while the same Action, being executed synchronously inside `ApiController`, does run through, and a different action, called asynchronously, also runs through.

Furthermore, when I call one action synchronously as well as the other action asynchronously, the asynchronous call fails as well.

- What does cause the `ThreadAbortException`?
- Is there anything I can do to get around the `ThreadAbortException`?

Code:

```
[HttpGet]
public string TestThreadAbortException()
{
    InitToolkit(); // Initialize Logger, DB etc.
    DebugController.DoAfter(5.Seconds(), MyAction); // Runs through!
    //TestThreadAbortException(logger); // Runs through!
    //Combining the first and the second line makes the first one throw the Exception as well.
    //DebugController.DoAfter(10.Seconds(), TestThreadAbortException); // throws Exception
    return String.Join("\r\n",logger.Flush());
}

private void TestThreadAbortException(Logger logger)
{
    Task<string> task = new Task<string>(MyMethod);
    task.Start();
    Task.Run(async () => await task);
    try
    {
        var result = ConfigureAwait(task, false).Result;
    }
    catch (System.AggregateException ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerExceptions.Count == 1)
        {
            throw ex.InnerExceptions[0];
        }
        throw;
    }
}

private async Task<string> ConfigureAwait(Task<string> task, bool continueOnCapturedContext)
{
    return await task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: continueOnCapturedContext);
}

private string MyMethod()
{
    Thread.Sleep(20000);
    return "Test";
}

private void MyAction(Logger logger)
{
    logger.Log(MyMethod());
}

public static void DoAfter(TimeSpan waitFor, Action<Logger> action)
{
    try {
        ThreadStart work = () =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(waitFor);
            DatabaseLogger logger = new DatabaseLogger();
            logger.Log("Executing " + action.Method.Name + ", " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            try
            {
                action.Invoke(logger);
                logger.Log("Successfully executed " + action.Method.Name + ", " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.Log("Error in " + action.Method.Name + ": " + e.Message + ", " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            }
            logger.CloseDatabase();
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(work);
        thread.Start();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Background information: In the production code, the inner async call, where during debugging I just create a new task, is created inside a Microsoft library that does not offer synchronous methods, so I won't be able to just "remove the Task".

Comment: Do not use `new Thread` with `async`!

Comment: @DavidPine Why not? Please elaborate.

Comment: Using `async` and `await` will handle this for you... there should be no need to start a new thread manually, especially on a web server.

Comment: ["The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) Well, I want to create a background thread that should not be awaited by the foreground process and should continue even after the foreground process has finished. Not entirely sure how to do that...

Comment: Constructing an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What causes the ThreadAbortException?

See [`ThreadAbortException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception(v=vs.110).aspx): "The exception that is thrown when a call is made to the Abort method". Avoid using all the manual `Thread` related code in the `DoAfter` method.

> Is there anything I can do to get around the ThreadAbortException?

Yes... utilize the `async` and `await` keywords correctly following best programming practices and patterns.

Here are my suggested modifications:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> TestThreadAbortException()
{
    InitToolkit(); // Initialize Logger, DB etc.

    var result = await DoAfter(5.Seconds(), MyAction);

    return result;
}
```

Mark your controller method as `Task<T>` returning, where `T` is the type to return. In this case a `string`.

If you need to simply start a background logging job and then return to the client, you should consider [`QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942716/why-use-async-with-queuebackgroundworkitem/36950086#36950086). Instead of using `Thread.Sleep` use `Task.Delay`, mark methods as `Task` or `Task<T>` that are representative of asynchronous operations.

```
public async Task<T> DoAfter<T>(TimeSpan waitFor, Func<Logger, Task<T>> action)
{
    await Task.Delay(waitFor);
    DatabaseLogger logger = new DatabaseLogger();
    logger.Log("Executing " + action.Method.Name + ", " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    try
    {
        return await action(logger);
        logger.Log("Successfully executed " + action.Method.Name + ", " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.Log("Error in " + action.Method.Name + ": " + e.Message + ", " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }
    finally
    {
        logger.CloseDatabase();
    }
}

private async Task MyAction(Logger logger)
{
    var result = await MyMethod();
    logger.Log(result);
}

private async Task<string> MyMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(20000);
    return "Test";
}
```

Comment: I think `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` is exactly what I searched for. Will open a new question for the issues I now have.