# Should one await a background, fire-and-forget Task?

Tags: c#, asp.net, task, background-process

What are the differences between these two fire-and-forget choices:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async () => await UpdateStatsAsync(id))
```

and

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(() => UpdateStatsAsync(id))
```

when it comes to queuing up some background work that the client doesn't really need to depend on?

Comment: Look at [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942716/why-use-async-with-queuebackgroundworkitem)

Comment: @Icemanind: Thanks, those answers aren't clear and also contradict each other. And Stephen Cleary's answer there talks about general async vs sync cases :/

Comment: The accepted answer is detailed and accurate. Cleary's answer is an odd contribution; doesn't really seem to address the practical elements of the question that was asked. But that doesn't mean that the question isn't an exact duplicate of yours.

Comment: Meh. You closed whilst I was answering. I record my answer here, if only to vent my spleen. The difference is that 

 - the first one spuriously wraps UpdateStatsAsync() in an extra Task
   which later has to be unwrapped again. 
 - the second one is easier to read.

Comment: Reopening; this question is about two different ways to queue asynchronous work to QBWI; [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942716/why-use-async-with-queuebackgroundworkitem) is about queueing asynchronous work vs queueing synchronous work.

Comment: Guys, this is very different from a standard question on return await. QBWI is the unknown vs a standard return

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use the non-async version, as `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` has an overload that takes a `CancellationToken` and returns a `Task`, so your code would look like:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => UpdateStatsAsync(id));
```

Internally this overload `await`s this function for you. One downside to this approach is if you are returning the `Task` from inside a `using` scope, or `try`/`catch`, you might get surprises by not awaiting your `Task`, but in this simple scenario you shouldn't need to worry about this.

Comment: Those surprises because of the underlying `async void` implementation in `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` ?

Comment: It is similar yes, so if you have a `try`/`catch` for example, if you do not `await` the `Task` returning method inside the `try` block, you will return a `Task` which when awaited on will throw. You could easily be forgiven for thinking you were catching that error, but because you didn't await *inside* the `try` block, you will not catch the exception there.